# C++ Stringstream assigning wrong value to variable?

Tags: c++, string, formatting, integer, stringstream

I have this section of code here

```
    cout << "Player 1 enter coordinate" << endl;
    int x, y;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    stringstream is(s);
    is >> x >> y;
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
```

When enter "1 2" into the terminal, cout prints out:

```
Player 1 enter coordinate
1 2  //input

1 4197944 //output
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong?"* Yes, you're not checking for errors. Here, the error occurs because `cin>>s` only reads until the next white-space. `is>>y` will fail, and `y` will not have been set. As it is not initialized either, you'll have Undefined Behaviour when trying to print `y`.

Comment: I didn't even realize. getLine() will solve this. Thank you.

Comment: You can also answer your own question, instead of adding the answer as an edit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use getline() instead of cin, since cin ends at whitespace.

Fixed version:

```
    std::cout << "Player 1 enter coordinate" << std::endl;
    int x, y;
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin,s);
    std::stringstream is(s);
    is >> x >> y;
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
```

Comment: Error checking is very easy: `if (std::getline(std::cin, s)) { std::stringstream is(s); if (is >> x >> y ) std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n'; else std::cerr << "error parsing x and/or y\n"; } else std::cerr << "error getting a line from standard input\n";`.  As DyP hints, you'll save yourself (and us, and any program users) grief if you make it a habit.

Answer (score 1):

The string 's' is only retrieving the first word '1'. Instead of bothering with stringstream, you can just use standard input stream directly.

```
cin >> x
cin >> y
```